# How to create global android device back button handler using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In my scenario, I am trying to create global class for android back button handler and reuse it in multiple screen class files. How to do it? I tried below code but I dont know how to access common class from other classes.

**My Code Below (Androidhandler.tsx)**

```
export default class hardware extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.BackButton = this.BackButton.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener'BackPress',this.BackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('BackPress',this.BackButton);
  }

  BackButton() {
    if(this.props.navigation){
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
        return true;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code allows to show an alert when you want to go back with the android back button, what you need is to use the react native **BackHandler** component as follows.

```
import { BackHandler } from "react-native"

export default class hardware extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.BackButton = this.BackButton.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.BackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
      if (this.props.navigator && this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
        this.navigator.pop();
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  }

  BackButton() {
    Alert.alert(
      'Warning',
      'Are you sure to leave?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          style: 'cancel'
        },
        { text: 'OK', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
      ],
    );
    return true;
    }
}
```